# How to set hieght of ion-datetime in presentation = time

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, web-component, shadow-dom

I am creating one of my first web apps with ionic.
My app is meant to control some sort of hardware using time schedules.
I am using ion-datetime with presentation="time" for this purpose and I found it to be a bit too high so I want to lower its height. 
This is code of my component with ion-datetime implemented:

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
            <ion-datetime presentation="time" hourCycle="h23" mode="ios"></ion-datetime>
            <ion-toggle></ion-toggle> 
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

And here is is css am using:

```
ion-datetime {
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px; /* Does not work either! */
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

According to official [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) there is no `--height` property or something like other ionic components have so only natural way to do this is regular css `height` property. 
But after setting size to 100px only some sort of viewport height will change while inner parts of ion-datetime will remain at original size resulting in something like this:

[image]

So my question is **what is the proper way to alter height of ion-datetime in presentation mode "time"**? 
Is there a way to do this without tempering with a shadow dom od ion-datetime component? 
 And if not, **how to alter the shadow dom to achive proper height results?**
Edit:
In case of this being important, I am using Ionic/Vue ^6.0.1 with Vue3 ^3.0.0 and here is css of ion-card but I think it is not conected with ion-card in any way...

```
ion-card {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 280px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transition: .5s;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I used flex to justify center and align center, with fixed height and width it centered everything. Obviously a temporary fix but it works so hey-ho

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).